# How to Manage Parent Child Relation Of Options In opencart

Tags: opencart

i want to add sub option with description depends On parent Option Like 
eye wear frame  power type(single vision,zero power)
sub options for single vision and and zero power

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new field to the database, or utilize an existing one that you don't currently use.

For example:
EAN

If you don't use EAN, you can simply change the name in the language files:
**your_directory/admin/language/en-gb/catalog/product.php**
Change:

```
$_['entry_ean']              = 'EAN';
```

to

```
$_['entry_ean']              = 'Single Vision';
```

and similarly for catalog.

Tags are also used in similar fashion, for items to link/group similar products.  (If you want all 'single vision' items to be linkable/grouped together, tags would be the easiest way to go.)